# Concise solution for number of sets contained within

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, pattern-matching

Let's say I have a short list of strings, that can contain duplicates: <"A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F">

Then let's say I have some other string lists, which may or may not be subsets of the original list. I need to know:

1. Does the second set "cover" the first set (e.g., is every item in the first set also contained in the second)?
2. If 1 is true, how many instances of the second set does it take to recreate the first set?

So, in this case, if my second set was the list: <"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F">, I would get TRUE and 2.

If it was the list: <"A", "B", "C">, I would get FALSE.

If my first was <"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C">:

- Second is <"A", "B", "C">: returns TRUE and 4.
- Second is <"A", "A", "B", "C">: returns TRUE and 3.

I know that this can be easily accomplished in N x M time using a nested loop. But I am looking for a (preferably Linq-based) solution that is concise and/or optimized. I played with **Linq.Except** but the problem with that is that it returns only the distinct elements, and is thereby useless when comparing lists of strings that contain duplicates.

Anyone have any unique ideas?

Comment: as usual...  What are the constraints?  You say you have a list of strings but in your example you give characters (which may be misleading).  So are these unique characters or are these strings?  How big can the lists be?  The let's say you have *"some other string lists"*... Say, how many other? How big? Do you want a theoretical solution not taking into account the physical limitation of the machine (your computer) you're using?

Comment: First one is a simple `Intersect` of two sets. And ask if the intersect is equal to a set (so no duplicates) of your first list.

Comment: @Syntax, they are strings. I just used characters in the examples for brevity. The lists are quite short, usually no longer than 10. The number of other lists varies but is also less than 10. Theoretical solutions are not necessary, just wondering if anyone has a clever and/or concise code snippet that can solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the second set "cover" the first set (e.g., is every item in the first set also contained in the second)?

```
// Assuming that the elements are comparable (strings are);
// if not, need to implement your own IComparer<T>
var doesCover = !original.Except(secondList).Any();
```

> How many instances of the second set does it take to recreate the first set?

```
var instancesRequired = secondList.GroupBy(e => e)
    .Max(gr => (original.Count(e => e.Equals(gr.Key))
               + gr.Count() - 1) / gr.Count());
```

**Caveat:** If both `original` and `secondList` are empty, then `doesCover` will be true but the calculation of `instancesRequired` will throw an exception. Might want to specifically check for empty lists therefore.